# Storing input from user as char array C | segmentation fault error

Tags: arrays, c, segmentation-fault

I am trying to take input from user and store it as a char array. I have the following code in which the function array, returns the address to the character array. However, I am getting a core dump error, what is happening here?

```
//reading and storing input from user as char array
int * array(int * r){
        int ch;
        int i;
        r[10];
        printf("enter your name: ");
        for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                r[i] = getc(stdin);
                printf("%c", r[i]);
        }
        return r;
}
//main
int main(void){
        int *p;
        p = array(p);
}
```

Comment: You never allocated any memory for `p`, so you're dereferencing an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: You should use a tutorial for learning how to read a string from standard input in C. You code does not follow the usual practices...

Comment: You say "char array" but you're using `int`.

Comment: The statement `r[10];` doesn't do anything. You also declare a variable `ch` that you never use at all.

Comment: Your code will work if you change `int *p;` to `int p[10];`

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to be similar to your code.

The array could be char, instead of int and many other things (you may pass len instead of hard-coding length etc). Anyway the major error was passing a pointer without initializing it: statically as I've done, 11 places, one is for null character; or dynamically using malloc.

The if statement is just for exiting the loop if someone press enter or the stream ends, I think it's your desired behavior.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
//reading and storing input from user as char array
void array(int * r){
        int ch;
        int i;
        //r[10];
        printf("enter your name: ");
        for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                int ch = getc(stdin);
                if ( ch == EOF || ch == '\n' || ch == '\r')
                    break;
                r[i] = ch;
                printf("%c", r[i]);
        }
        r[i] = 0;
        
}
//main
int main(void){
        int p[11];
        array(p);
        printf("\nExit\n");
}
```